# Orbeon workflow send button : How to add a form url in the email body

Tags: orbeon

I am sending email with PDF as an attachment.

Now I want to add form link in body of this email.
This link is the **URL to that saved form**.

How to achieve this?

---

I have tried something as follow :

```
      <xsl:variable name="doc" select="doc('input:parameters')/*/document" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="xpl:rewriteServiceURI(concat('/fr/',$app,'/',$form, '/edit/',$doc), true())"/>

      <!-- 
         <xsl:value-of select="$fr-resources/resource[@xml:lang = $request-language]/email/body"/> 
      -->
```

I am getting result as expected . adding **URL of current document to email body**.

But If i use **xpl:rewriteServiceURI** or **xpl:rewriteResourceURI** it gives me same result !

Which one I have to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change `email-form.xpl`. Right now the text in the body is static. You can see how it is [pulled from the resources](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-4.3.1.0-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/email/email-form.xpl#L226). There, you want to generate a URL that points back to your server, and for this need to know the app, form, and document id. These informations are available as `doc('input:parameters')/*/app`, `doc('input:parameters')/*/form`, and `doc('input:parameters')/*/document`, so you should be able to generate the link with XSLT. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried that out.)

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="xpl:rewriteServiceURI(concat('/fr/',$app,'/',$form, '/edit/',$doc), true())"/>                                                    Which i have to use , xpl:rewriteServiceURI or xpl:rewriteResourceURI

Comment: It's `xpl:rewriteServiceURI` you want to call. You'll let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, Its works for me.... <xsl:value-of select="pipeline:rewriteServiceURI(concat('/fr/',$app,'/',$form, '/edit/',$doc), true())"/>